# Spring mvc redirect the same url to different hosts

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url, redirect

There is now two different domain names **a.com** and **b.com** that are bound to the same IP. When I use the **a.com/xxx** I enter the controller to perform the redirect operation, it jumps to the **b.com/test**. Why does this happen?

Controller.java :

```
@RequestMapping("/xxx")
public String campFinish() {
    //do something
    return "redirect/test";
}

@RequestMapping("/test")
public String campFinish() {
    //do something
    return "some page";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's `redirect:/test`. Your problem, however, has nothing to do with Spring. It's with your dns config. The first domain name to get **resolved** will show up. Either it is **b.com** or **a.com**.